# Spring Batch process XMl message from MQ (IBM Websphere)

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-batch, ibm-mq

I am new to spring batch. I have a message xml in MQ i want to process this message through Spring batch. 
can we integrate spring batch to MQ directly? or with the help of Camel ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`JmsItemReader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/jms/JmsItemReader.html). It will read via JMS Template.